# Creating memory snapshot from inside the code (Java)

Tags: java, memory, profiling, snapshot

Is there a possibility, that from inside your program, by calling some java library, make java create memory snapshot of that program? (default .hprof file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a heap dump in your application using the example [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via JMX - which means that you have to go out to come back in, so to speak.  Details on how to do it via code are available [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/programmatically_dumping_heap_from_java).